# How to get all browser's installed on a machine with its install location and browser version (including Chrome dev, canary..etc) using cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

Hello i am developing a application using selenium and python 3.7 to automatically update the browser driver by getting old version and new version from browser's website and i want this for other chrome builds also like canary etc... i am new to command-line and registry so i am unable to figure it out.

i have also tried this code :-

```
@echo off
setlocal enableExtensions

echo.
echo.
echo INSTALLED BROWSERS
echo.
echo.

rem :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
rem :: exporting registry values for installed browsers
rem :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

rem for 64 bit systems
START /W REGEDIT /E "%Temp%\BROW3.reg" HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Clients\StartMenuInternet
rem for 32 bit systems
if not exist "%Temp%\BROW3.reg" START /W REGEDIT /E "%Temp%\BROW3.reg" HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet

setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%B in ('type "%Temp%\BROW3.reg" ^| findstr /E "DefaultIcon]"') do (
  rem extracting browser name from icon path
  set "browser=%%B"
  rem removing \DefaultIcon] string
  set "browser=!browser:\DefaultIcon]=!"
  rem get the browser name
  for %%P in ("!browser!") do echo %%~nP
)
endLocal

echo.
echo.
echo EXECUTABLES PATHS
echo.
echo.

setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims=@=" %%B in ('type "%Temp%\BROW3.reg" ^| findstr /B "@" ^| findstr /E ".exe\\\",0\"^"') do (
  set "browser=%%~B"
  set "browser=!browser:\\=\!"
  echo !browser!

)
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims=@=" %%B in ('type "%Temp%\BROW3.reg" ^| findstr /B "@" ^| findstr /E ".exe,0\"^"') do (
  set "browser=%%~B"
  set "browser=!browser:\\=\!"
  set "browser=!browser:,0=!"
  echo !browser!

)
endLocal


rem delete temp file
del /Q /F "%Temp%\BROW3.reg"


echo.
echo.
echo DEFAULT BROWSER
echo.
echo.

START /W REGEDIT /E "%Temp%\BROW5.reg" HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f tokens^=3^ delims^=^" %%B in ('type "%Temp%\BROW5.reg" ^| find "@"') do (
    set "default=%%B"
    rem removing double slashes
    set "default=!default:\\=\!"
    rem removing end slash
    set "default=!default:~0,-1!"
    rem get the name
    for %%D in ("!default!") do echo %%~nD
)
endLocal
del /Q /F "%Temp%\BROW5.reg"

echo.
echo.
echo DEFAULT .HTML VIEWER
echo.
echo.

START /W REGEDIT /E "%Temp%\BROW6.reg" HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\htmlfile\shell\open\command
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f tokens^=3^ delims^=^" %%B in ('type "%Temp%\BROW6.reg" ^| find "@"') do (
    set "default=%%B"
    set "default=!default:\\=\!"
    set "default=!default:~0,-1!"
    for %%D in ("!default!") do echo %%~nD
)
endLocal
del /Q /F "%Temp%\BROW6.reg"
echo.
echo.
pause
```

Output:-
But does not show location for chrome dev

```
INSTALLED BROWSERS

Firefox-308046B0AF4A39CB
Google Chrome
Google Chrome Dev
IEXPLORE
Microsoft Edge

EXECUTABLES PATHS

C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe
C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe

DEFAULT BROWSER
iexplore

DEFAULT .HTML VIEWER
iexplore

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: The reason you aren't getting the full filepath is because of `for %%P in ("!browser!") do echo %%~nP`. The `%~n0` extension only gets the name of the variable whilst `%~f0` gets the full filename. Try using `echo %%~fP` in the for loop instead of `%%~nP`

Comment: I reread your question and seem to have misunderstood it in my previous comment, but you should still take note of that since it will still be useful in the `EXECUTABLE PATH` section ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off

echo:
echo INSTALLED BROWSERS
echo:

for /f "delims=" %%A in (
    'reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet /k /f *'
) do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2,*" %%B in (
        '2^>nul reg query "%%~A\defaulticon" /ve ^| findstr /v "^HKEY"'
    ) do (
        echo "%%~nD"
    )
)

echo:
echo EXECUTABLES PATHS
echo:

for /f "delims=" %%A in (
    'reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet /k /f *'
) do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2,*" %%B in (
        '2^>nul reg query "%%~A\shell\open\command" /ve ^| findstr /v "^HKEY"'
    ) do (
        echo "%%~D"
    )
)

echo:
echo DEFAULT BROWSER
echo:

for /f "tokens=1,2,*" %%A in (
    'reg query HKCR\http\shell\open\command /ve ^| findstr /v "^HKEY"'
) do (
    echo "%%~nC"
)

echo:
echo DEFAULT .HTML VIEWER
echo:

for /f "tokens=1,2,*" %%A in (
    'reg query HKCR\htmlfile\shell\open\command /ve ^| findstr /v "^HKEY"'
) do (
    echo "%%~nC"
)

echo:
pause
```

Can eliminate use of temporary files with `reg query` and avoid `regedit` which may require administrator privileges.

The output is double quoted though you can remove the quotes if desired.

No named variables are used so `setlocal` is not used.

I do not have Chrome Dev installed so testing if detected is unknown from my current environment so I will show the output I do get on Windows 7:

> ```
> INSTALLED BROWSERS
>
> "firefox"
> "chrome"
> "iexplore"
>
> EXECUTABLES PATHS
>
> "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
> "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
>
> DEFAULT BROWSER
>
> "iexplore"
>
> DEFAULT .HTML VIEWER
>
> "iexplore"
>
> Press any key to continue . . .
> ```

If you want browser versions, this example for Firefox version may help guide the way:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,*" %%A in (
    '2^>nul reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox" /ve ^| findstr /v "^HKEY"'
) do (
    echo "%%~C"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```bat
@echo off
setlocal enableExtensions

echo.
echo.
echo INSTALLED BROWSERS
echo.
echo.

rem :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
rem :: exporting registry values for installed browsers
rem :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

rem for 64 bit systems
START /W REGEDIT /E "%Temp%\BROW3.reg" HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Clients\StartMenuInternet
rem for 32 bit systems
if not exist "%Temp%\BROW3.reg" START /W REGEDIT /E "%Temp%\BROW3.reg" HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet

setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%B in ('type "%Temp%\BROW3.reg" ^| findstr /E "DefaultIcon]"') do (
  rem extracting browser name from icon path
  set "browser=%%B"
  rem removing \DefaultIcon] string
  set "browser=!browser:\DefaultIcon]=!"
  rem get the browser name
  for %%P in ("!browser!") do echo %%~nP
)
endLocal

echo.
echo.
echo EXECUTABLES PATHS
echo.
echo.

setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims=@=" %%B in ('type "%Temp%\BROW3.reg" ^| findstr /B "@" ^| findstr /E ".exe\\\",0\"^"') do (
  set "browser=%%~fB"
  set "browser=!browser:\\=\!"
  echo !browser!

)
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims=@=" %%B in ('type "%Temp%\BROW3.reg" ^| findstr /B "@" ^| findstr /E ".exe,0\"^"') do (
  set "browser=%%~fB"
  set "browser=!browser:\\=\!"
  set "browser=!browser:,0=!"
  echo !browser!

)
endLocal


rem delete temp file
del /Q /F "%Temp%\BROW3.reg"

echo.
echo.
echo DEFAULT BROWSER
echo.
echo.

START /W REGEDIT /E "%Temp%\BROW5.reg" HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f tokens^=3^ delims^=^" %%B in ('type "%Temp%\BROW5.reg" ^| find "@"') do (
    set "default=%%B"
    rem removing double slashes
    set "default=!default:\\=\!"
    rem removing end slash
    set "default=!default:~0,-1!"
    rem get the name
    for %%D in ("!default!") do echo %%~nD
)
endLocal
del /Q /F "%Temp%\BROW5.reg"

echo.
echo.
echo DEFAULT .HTML VIEWER
echo.
echo.

START /W REGEDIT /E "%Temp%\BROW6.reg" HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\htmlfile\shell\open\command
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f tokens^=3^ delims^=^" %%B in ('type "%Temp%\BROW6.reg" ^| find "@"') do (
    set "default=%%B"
    set "default=!default:\\=\!"
    set "default=!default:~0,-1!"
    for %%D in ("!default!") do echo %%~nD
)
endLocal
del /Q /F "%Temp%\BROW6.reg"
echo.
echo.
pause
```

This should solve your issue with `Chrome Dev`, however, there are some errors with the `DEFAULT BROWSER` and `DEFAULT HTML VIEWER` sections of the file which I do not understand why it doesn't work. One thing that I noticed with my default html handler and browser, Brave, they create their own html tag `Brave HTML Document` which is separate to `htmlfile` in the registry and `ftype` command. `ftype` output for me shows `Brave HTML file` alone and `iexplorer` as my default html and https handler which both are incorrect. I don't know why this is and I want to know as well but since that is a different problem, you should ask a different question for it.